# Free Tools for Information Retrieval?

Tags: information-retrieval

Which freely available tools are recommended for performing Information Retrieval using Generalized Vector Space, Naïve Bayes, and Fuzzy Set models?

Answer (score 0):

Generalized Vector Space will probably be very hard to found. I know because I've implemented it for a college course.
You can still get "Normal" Vector Space with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).
For the others I guess you can take a look at [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/). The [Naive Bayes classifier](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/bayesian.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is this post, i think it could be useful to create your own using TDIDF. It is a compromise and it is not complicated.

http://marcocattai.posterous.com/creating-a-simple-spotlight-search-using-core